# State of React Component, wrong order of objects in array from response

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, websocket

I'm getting data to React app via websocket. I've one big object, which holds data of game. One of it's property is array of player objects, like so:

```
{
  propertyX: "X",
  players: [{player1}, {player2}, {player3}],
  propertyY: "Y"
}
```

Problem is that in my database and response from websocket (Network Tab in Chrome) the order of which those player objects where pushed is preserved, even when I console.log it just before I insert game into state of Component is okay. However then when I access state I get different order of players in this array, it is ordered by place that they scored in game.

From this original data:

```
players: [{ place: 2 }, { place: 3 }, { place: 1 }]
```

I got this in my state:

```
players: [{ place: 1 }, { place: 2 }, { place: 3 }]
```

What could be the reason of such behaviour?

@edit
This line of code for one of game

```
console.log(game.players[0].place) 
this.setState({ game }, () => {
  console.log("callback", game.players[0].place, this.state.game.players[0].place)
});
```

Outputs:

```
4
callback, 1, 1
```

Added pastebin with whole component code:
https://pastebin.com/hHLQMR6y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are logging the same reference twice - `game.players[0].place` and it shows different data, you are mutating it somewhere.

Remember that this.setState() does a shallow merge, so if you are accessing `game` object after the `setState` line (e.g. doing `game.players = ...`) you are mutating both the local variable and the state that was generated from it.

Comment: I confirm that this was the issue, I was using `.sort()` in one of child components without creating a copy so it was mutating original props passed down from parent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without seeing your code I don't have much to go on, but it may be that you're incorrectly setting the state. Something else to consider is that `this.setState({})` doesn't happen immediately, it's actually asynchronous. So, if you try to access the state before it's been set you'll receive old data. You can provide a callback function as a second argument to run after the state has been set:

```
const callback = () => {
    console.log(this.state.players);
}

this.setState({
    players: newPlayers
}, callback);
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my question, I'm console logging inside of callback and I'm getting there wrong order data, so it is something with it, but I've no idea what is the reason for that.

Comment: In your console.log you are accessing the game object directly. You need to use `this.state.game.players[0].place`. When using objects in the state be sure to only use `this.state` to access them and `this.setState({})` to update them. When updating make a clone of the object and update the state with the clone.

Comment: Unfortunately if I do `this.state.game.players[0].place` behaviour is the same, I get wrong order. Also, setting state shouldn't mutate my original variable from response, and it seems like it does.